# VS Code криво показывает кириллицу во вкладке "Выходные данные" (Python). Не могу победить

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

Всем доброго дня!

Вопрос явно избитый, но почему-то не могу нагуглить ответ. Вопрос простой: пишу код на Python в VSCode(обновлен до последней версии), надо посмотреть вывод во вкладке "Выходные данные". В частности код затягивает построчно текстовый файл с указанием параметра encoding="utf-8", потом пихает его в Pandas DataFrame. Мне нужно посмотреть результат, но во вкладке "Выходные данные" вместо кириллицы показываются кракозябры. В терминале (терминал штатный, ничего нового не накручивал) - все нормально, при запуске в интерактивном окне - тоже кириллица есть. А в "Выходных данных" - нет.

Единственное, что принесло результат: Ставил галку в настройках самой Win11, в пункте "Бета-версия. Юникод (UTF-8) для поддержки языка во всем мире". Помогает в VSCode, но появляются кракозябры в других программах. Пришлось галку убрать.

Да, можно забить и пользоваться терминалом/интерактивным окном. Но вот удобнее мне в "Выходных данных" смотреть, ничего не могу с собой поделать. Явно ведь какое-то простое решение есть. Но не догоняю. Прошу помощи.

[image: Вот скрин]

1. Ставил галку в настройках самой Win11, в пункте "Бета-версия. Юникод (UTF-8) для поддержки языка во всем мире". Помогает в VSCode, но появляются кракозябры в других программах. Пришлось галку убрать.
2. Пробовал в settings.json менять в разделе code-runner.executorMap
   "python": "python -u" на "python": "set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 && py -u"
   Это вообще не сработало, сразу ошибка лезет. Причем не прочитаешь, т.к. кракозябры опять выводятся. И копипаст в перекодировщик тоже не помогает - не получается все равно ошибку прочитать.

Comment: Просто отключите (или вообще удалите) code runner. Для запуска кода на python вполне хватает просто расширения для Python (и оно при этом более функционально, например нормально поддерживает виртуальные окружения).

Comment: Попробовал, к сожалению это не совсем то. Без CodeRunner результат выполнения кода просто выводится в терминале. Этот вариант у меня и так работает, даже при в включенном CodeRunner. 
Но за подсказку все равно спасибо! По крайней мере проблема локализуется в конкретном плагине

Comment: Не вижу проблемы в том, что будет выводиться просто в терминале.

Comment: @insolor, проблемы нет. Просто мне удобнее вывод смотреть во вкладке "Выходные данные".

Answer (score 2):

В общем нашел решение. Я в пункте 2, где описывал предпринятые действия, делал почти вес правильно, только параметр менял не в том разделе. Надо менять именно в разделе, относящемся к CodeRunner. У меня заработало, русскиз показывается нормально теперь.

[Вот ссылка на статью](https://russianblogs.com/article/17841250492/)